# how to hide parent Navigators header?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile-development

This is my parent Navigator
[Parent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLb7E.png)

This is child navigator
[Child](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tThkn.png)

when the results screen is viewed I need to hide HomeNavigators header

I tried using redux to hide the header. But it showed latency while rendering UI. I didn't find any solution regarding this anywhere Please let me know how can I achive this